# imagettftext with utf characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP's imagettftext for utf characters (Chinese Simplified) but it doesn't seems to work - it's showing weird characters. I'm using Arial.tff as the text.

```
imagettftext($img, $textSize, 0, $locX, $locY, $color, $font, $line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your font has to have those unicode character you want to print. Does Arial.ttf contain all chars you want? You can check this with "Character Map" tool on Windows.

Comment: And there is practically the same question in here, just have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582855/east-asian-characters-rendered-as-squares-with-php-imagettftext